# Merge two rows into one row Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, merge

I am new to Oracle PL/SQL.

I managed to program a function in which every time I received a text file it would be loaded into the table ***INTER*** and from there into ***TABLE1***.

But now I am supposed to be receiving two files with data that is going to be loaded into table ***INTER***. One of them with a certain number of fields and the other one with the rest of the fields (NEW1,NEW2,NEW3). 
I need to combine all the information so when I am loading into ***TABLE1*** it is merged into one row.

But I have no clue on how I can achieve that...I would appreciate any help...

Here you have the code I was using (I added the new fields)

```
MERGE 
            INTO TABLE1 T1
                 USING (SELECT INTR.A
                                  , INTR.M
                                  , INTR.CODL
                                  , INTR.CODP
                                  , INTR.EX
                                  , INTR.SLS
                                  , INTR.MRG
                                  --, INTR.NEW1
                                 -- , INTR.NEW2
                                 -- , INTR.NEW3
                                  , T2.COD2
                         FROM INTER INTR,
                              TABLE2 T2,
                              LOCALIZATION LOC,
                            (SELECT M,A FROM DATES GROUP BY M,A)  DAYS
                         WHERE INTR.A = DAYS.A
                         AND INTR.M = DAYS.M
                         AND INTR.CODP = T2.CODP
                         AND INTR.CODL = LOC.CODL) INTER
                    ON 
                    ( (T1.A = INTER.A)
                    AND (T1.M = INTER.M)
                    AND (T1.CODL = INTER.CODL)
                    AND (T1.CODP = INTER.CODP)
                    AND (T1.COD2 = INTER.COD2)
                    )
            WHEN MATCHED
            THEN
               UPDATE SET
               T1.EX             =    INTER.EX  
               ,T1.SLS           =    INTER.SLS
               ,T1.MRG           =    INTER.SLS
                --,T1.NEW1          =   INTER.NEW1
                --,T1.NEW2          =   INTER.NEW2
                --,T1.NEW3          =   INTER.NEW3
                ,T1.FLG     =   'Y'
                ,T1.FECM     =  null
            WHEN NOT MATCHED
            THEN
               INSERT     (
                    A              
                    ,M              
                    ,CODL          
                    ,COD2      
                    ,CODP      
                    ,EX          
                    ,SLS          
                    ,MRG
                --  ,NEW1
                --  ,NEW2
                --  ,NEW3                       
                    ,FLG   
                    ,FECM 
                    ,FECC      
               )
                   VALUES (                                     
                          INTER.A
                        , INTER.M
                        , INTER.CODL
                        , INTER.COD2
                        , INTER.CODP
                        , INTER.EX
                        , INTER.SLS
                        , INTER.MRG
                        /*

                        */
                        , 'Y'
                        , null
                        , SYSDATE         
                        );
```

Thanks a lot.

** I meant PL/SQL code but somehow the spell checker changed it

INTER  TABLE

A   NUMBER(4,0)
M   NUMBER(6,0) 
CODL    NUMBER(10,0) 
CODP    NUMBER(4,0)
EX  NUMBER(10,2) 
SLS NUMBER(10,2)
MRG NUMBER(10,2)
NEW1    NUMBER(10,2)
NEW2    NUMBER(10,2) 
NEW3    NUMBER(10,2)

TABLE1

A   NUMBER(4,0)
M   NUMBER(6,0)
CODL    NUMBER(10,0)
COD2    NUMBER(4,0)
CODP    NUMBER(4,0)
EX  NUMBER(10,2)
SLS NUMBER(10,2)
MRG NUMBER(10,2)
NEW1    NUMBER(10,2)
NEW2    NUMBER(10,2)
NEW3    NUMBER(10,2)
FLG VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
FECM    DATE
FECC    DATE

[example of rows and combination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIKJL.png)

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the question tags and describe *all* the fields on INTER - their name, their data type, and describe the data they contain. Please include information on the primary key column(s) of INTER. Also please include test data which shows examples of the pairs of rows, and then show how you expect those rows to be combined. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using different table to load new data?

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language, quite different from the Oracle dialect of SQL. I will edit your question to remove all references to PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `coalesce` (optionally `nvl` or `case when`) solve your problem? Only `update` clause needs modification:

```
...
when matched then update set
    t1.ex     =   coalesce(inter.ex, t1.ex),
    ...
    t1.new1   =   coalesce(inter.new1, t1.new1),
    ...
    t1.flg    =   'Y',
    t1.fecm   =   null
```